# Do the inhabitants of Sanctuary speak Rankene or some different local language?

Tags: thieves-world

I'm a couple of books into the Thieves' World series, and the question says it all.  Do the people who live in Sanctuary speak Rankene in their day to day lives or some Ilsigian language or "Sanctuarian" of some sort or what?  We see the Rankan officials talking to locals, but that could go either way.

I don't know if this is specifically addressed, but I thought it worth a shot to ask.

Comment: +1 Welcome to SFF.SE!

Answer (score 6):

As I recall, early in Book 1 we see Hakiem the storyteller giving some kids an outline of the history of the city of Sanctuary. It becomes clear that it's been a while -- at least a few generations -- since the Rankan Empire moved in and conquered the place. That suggests that, ever since then, the only sensible thing for parents to do would to be raise their kids to speak the preferred language of the Empire. So I'd speculate that, right after the conquest, there may have been thousands and thousands of local residents who were comfortable with Ilsigi as their native tongue, and had little or no grasp of Rankene -- but if they had any sense, they carefully raised the next generation to be able to communicate smoothly in common Rankene. Several of those families may have ended up being bilingual.

As you said, there are lots of scenes where people who were (at least presumably) born and raised in the vicinity of Sanctuary, such as Hanse, aka "Shadowspawn," find themselves having conversations with government officials. For instance, with Prince Kadakithis himself, and with the handful of elite bodyguards called "Hell Hounds" whom his brother the Emperor had sent along to keep an eye on him. Shadowspawn, in his debut story in Volume 1, has a serious talk with Kadakithis at the end of the story, and others in later volumes, and I don't recall them having any trouble understanding each other, even though Shadowspawn had not received any formal education to speak of in his childhood. (As we learn when Kadakithis shows him an official document, and then realizes his new acquaintance simply can't read! But there's no suggestion that a "language barrier" was the problem there.)

Nor do I recall any other scene in which Kadakithis, or any other Rankan character, discovers an interpreter is desperately needed in order to establish clear communication with a "local son or daughter" who had grown up in Sanctuary. You'd think this would happen regularly if the typical shopkeeper, blacksmith, street urchin, etc., were not in the habit of speaking common Rankene. So I have to say that the vast lack of evidence of the need for such interpreters signifies that they simply were not necessary in day-to-day interactions between the long-time denizens of Sanctuary and any new arrivals from other parts of the Empire. Common Rankene had long since become the default in that city.

Comment: +1 ¿Por que no los dos? Lots of societies, including empires, have many languages at play in a single locale.

Comment: Although it's equally likely that the rulers would quickly pick up fluency in the common tongue, at the very least so that they could supervise their torturer effectively. There was a question on SE a few months ago about how quickly Rurik's descendants adopted Russian culture, with the answer- backed up by religious records etc.- being "very".